# How can I treat an inheriting object as a subclass in OpenERP?

Tags: python, odoo

This question is perhaps more complicated than it would initially seem.

Let's say I have a parent class Animal (we name it in OpenERP as `animal.base`).  I also have subclasses Lion (`animal.lion`) and Elephant (`animal.elephant`).  I need to be able to create a view with a many2one field that can refer to any subclass of Animal.  This seems to work by doing the following:

```
class animal_lion(osv.osv):
    _name = 'animal.lion'
    _inherits = {'animal.base': 'base_id'}

    _columns = {
         ...
         'base_id': fields.many2one('animal.base', "Base ID")
    }

    def roar(self, cr, uid, context=None):
        print "rarrrrr"
```

Now when we create an instance of `animal.lion` we can see that it is visible in views that reference `animal.base`.  (Plain `inherit = 'animal.base'` does not behave this way, FWIW.)

However, now let's say we need to use a method from this animal.  Since the many2one refers simply to `animal.base`, we have no idea what kind of animal the user selected in the view.  Even if we happen to know that only lions will ever be chosen, we can't call `roar` because the `animal.base` object will only let us call methods that are defined on itself.   We can try to hack around it by naming the method `emit_sound` and trying to override the method in the Lion class.  This will at least run (once you add an `_inherit` in addition to the `_inherits`) but it won't produce the correct Lion-specific output.  What is needed is some way to determine the dynamic type of the specific instance that was chosen in a many2one on base class `x` where multiple subclasses specify `_inherits` on that same class `x`.  Imagine a fictional method `get_subtype()`.  Then we can say the following in our button handler for the view:

```
def perform(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    this = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context)
    subtype_name = this.my_many2one.get_subtype()
    subtype = self.pool.get(subtype_name)
    # will produce a roar if user picked a lion, else a meep
    subtype.emit_sound(cr, uid, context)
```

Alternatively, is there any other architecture that can be used to accomplish the same task?  (Yes, I contrived the example, but it should illustrate the real issue.)  [Perhaps encode the subtype name in a field in each subtype instance? ]

I am restricted to OpenERP v5, but would be interested to know the answer for any version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is that you want your `base.animal` to exist on its own in the database as a common index of all animals, so this complicates your data model substantially and forces you to use record-level inheritance (via `_inherits`).

In order to resolve the subtype for an animal you should add an explicit `type` column in `animal.base`, and always set it properly so you can infer the subtype record.

```
# This static list could also be replaced by a function
ANIMALS = [
    ('lion', 'Lion'),
    ('elephant', 'Elephant'),
]
class animal_base(osv.osv):
    _name = 'animal.base'
    _columns = {
         ...
         'type': fields.selection(ANIMALS, 'Type'), 
    }
```

Your `base.animals` will exist in the database on their own and can have their own views, because you're using a record-level inheritance. The *subtype* (e.g lion) can be seen as a "decoration" for each animal, and it might actually not be unique (both a `base.lion` and a `base.elephant` record could exist for the same `base.animal` record), so you should add uniqueness constraints somewhere.

Now, you should never have both `_inherit` and `_inherits` pointing to the same parent model, these two inheritance schemes are really meant for different purposes, as explained in the OpenERP [technical memento](http://doc.openerp.com/memento).
Instead you can have proxy methods in `animal.base` that will roughly look like your `perform` method, except they need to find out the ID of the child records in addition to their type, e.g.:

```
def emit_sound(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    for this in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
       animal_registry = self.pool['animal.%s' % this.type]
       animal_ids = animal_registry.search(cr, uid, 
           [('base_id','=',this.id)], context)
       assert len(animal_ids) == 1, 'Chimera alert! ;-)'
       animal_registry.emit_sound(cr, uid, animal_ids, context)
```

Of course you could refine this in several ways, for example with function fields added to `base.animal` to automate more of this plumbing work.

---

On the other hand, if you don't *really* need the `base.animal` to exist next to the other real animals, but simply need a way to select an arbitrary animal in a form view, you could try to use the traditional inheritance with `_inherit` + `_name`, with `base.animal` being an abstract base class for them (without actually holding any record).
Selecting an arbitrary animal could them be done with a `fields.reference`, on which you can filter the list of destination models. The 5.0 `subscription` module contains [an example with the `doc_source` field](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/5.0/view/2936/subscription/subscription.py#L67).
Watch out, `fields.reference` is something hybrid that does not integrate seamlessly with e.g. `browse`, `read` or `search`. It's stored as a string in the form `'model,id'` and you'll have to split the value manually whenever you need to dereference it - so be careful if you go that path. The only place where it's integrated as a pseudo-`many2one` is on the client UI, everywhere else it's just a plain, dumb string value.